# Is it possible to bind 2 identical devices on an x86 device with 2 different drivers?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, x86, linux-device-driver, device-tree

If I have some (identical) SMBus devices on my x86, is it possible to bind one driver to some of them and another driver to the rest?

If it is in an ARM device, we can modify the device-tree, and specify the driver to use for each of them. Is something like that possible in x86?

Comment: I think you can do this with the `driverctl` utility (you may need to install it) as long as the device is on a bus that supports the `driver_override` attribute (this is true for I2C client devices for example).

Comment: Yes, for most of the device drivers you may do unbind the device and bind back using another driver. No specific tools needed.

Comment: I meant, simultaneously. If we have 2 i2c devices with the same addess, say 0x40 on i2c-0 and i2c-1, is it possible to assign driver X for device @ i2c-0 and driver Y for device @ i2c-1?